# Calculate number of different elements in element-wise comparison

Tags: arrays, numpy

Suppose I have two NumPy arrays:

```
A = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9]
B = [1, 2, 5, 3, 5, 8, 10]
```

Is there any built-in function for element-wise comparison and output number of different elements? In the example above, output 4 (index: 1, 2, 4, 6 are different)

Comment: There's no single built-in. Just compare and count with `np.sum()` or `np.count_nonzero`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single function (you'll need two), but you can use NumPy `not_equal` and `count_nonzero`:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.count_nonzero(np.not_equal(A, B)))
# 4
```

This is significantly faster than `np.not_equal(A, B).sum()`.